# Enforce a protected constructor in deriving class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is there any mechanism that allows to enforce a protected constructor in a deriving class?

Simple example:

```
template<typename T>
class Factory;

class Base {
  template<typename T>
  friend class Factory;
protected:
  Base();
};


class Child : public Base {
public:
  Child(); // this should lead to a compile time error
};

<template T>
class Factory {
Base* GetNew()
{
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_base_of<Base, T>::value);

  Base* b = new T();
  b->doStuff();

  return b;
 }
};
```

So I want the Child class to be only creatable by the factory and enforce that all child classes deriving from Base have a protected constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way to enforce this. In general, base classes are very limited in how they can constrain subclasses. `Base` is not, and should not try to be, responsible for policing everyone who might ever write a class that happened to inherit from `Base`.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, <s>no</s> kind of.

`protected` is the least useful access specifier since any derived class is free to make the name (including the name of a constructor) public.

What you *can* do is use an access key in the constructor to ensure that only a factory creates the class.

```
struct factory;

// create_key's constructor is private, but the factory is a friend.
class create_key
{
  create_key() {};
  friend factory;
};

struct only_from_factory
{
  // base constructor demands a key is sent. Only a factory may create a key.
  only_from_factory(const create_key&) {};
};
```

Comment: Thanks this very good idea. I was actually thinking about something similar already. I would like to accept your answer as well but unfortunately i can only accept one.

Comment: that's ok. i don't do this for the glory. I do it because (a) it keeps me alert and (b) I happen to think that c++ is a fantastic language and I like to see it used well.